# XML for mobile clients

Tags: xml, java-me, mobile

I have a J2ME application that needs to communicate with my server, and download information for the application in XML.
My application could run a lot faster if I had a better format of data, which would allow me to have more efficient parsing code.

Does anyone know an efficient substitute for XML? Maybe something specific for mobile phones?

Answer (score 1):

[Best binary XML format for JavaME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599/best-binary-xml-format-for-javame)

The conclusion being [WBXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WBXML) which I would agree with.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/). Very compact binary encoding and highly optimised parser/encoder.  In short, you write some descriptions about your structures, and it compiles to a specialized OOP library in Java, C++ or Python that you include in your client and server.

Comment: no idea; but you can try.... after all, the PB compiler generates a library; i'd be surprised if it had any 'big Java' requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There's always JSON, but I don't know if it is what you need.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard about many protocols for this kind of stuff (efficient and small) but you could try Hessian which is a lot better than xml in terms of efficiency.

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/hessian.xtp

but be weary and check out the following which might help

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=j2me+hessian

Specifically

[What are the best remoting technologies for mobile applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82691/what-are-the-best-remoting-technologies-for-mobile-applications)